# setting up yum in stripped down linux

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

I have a box that contains minimal binaries needed to run Scientific Linux. What I want to do is to install additional programs. I could get rpm installed and tried to install yum but resolving those dependencies is a pain. Is there any easy way to do this?. What I want is to have all these basic utilities installed without much effort.At least if I could get yum to work without manually resolving each dependencies that would be great. I don't have physical access to the box.

Comment: This should be on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Since Scientific Linux is RH based, it seems that there is some relevant info at that link [http://techtrouts.com/how-to-install-yum-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-4](http://techtrouts.com/how-to-install-yum-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-4/)